# How to insert a variable value using flex?

Tags: regex, lex, flex-lexer

The raw sample data looks something like this:

```
neg      
test  
-1.0 1.0    
-2.1 3.45
```

and i have to convert it using flex into a recognized ocaml input list like this:

```
let test  
=[  
[ -1.0 ; 1.0 ; 1.0; -1.0 ];  
[ -2.1 ; 3.45 ; 1.0; -1.0 ]  
];;
```

I'm able to convert it as follows:

```
let test  
=[  
[ -1.0 ; 1.0 ; 1.0 ; ]; 
[ -2.1 ; 3.45 ; 1.0 ; ]
];;
```

The main question that i have is:

> 1. How to put the last element in each list as -1 if raw data says neg and as 1 if raw data says pos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it right with the `<<EOF>>` regex. The only thing you missed is that you somehow need to either directly or indirectly terminate the scanner within the `<<EOF>>` code-block.

In my case I am using jflex and my problem is sufficiently simple I use it in the default %standalone mode. So my `<<EOF>>` is as follows:

```
<<EOF>>    {
               printJson(System.out);
               System.out.flush();
               System.exit(0);
           }
```

Where `printJson()` serializes the global datastructure the scanner has been building up to the nominated file stream. In your case it sounds like things are simple enough you are probably even simpler:

```
<<EOF>>    {
               printf(" ]\n];;");
               flush(stdout);
               exit(0);
           }
```

If you are not standalone, you need to return an EOF token that is handled appropriately by whatever process is calling your generated scanner.

Good luck.